# how to solve the problem of selecting multiple rows

Tags: sas

I have the data in this format- it is just an

example: n=2

```
X      Y      info

2      1       good
2      4       bad

3      2      good

4     1       bad
4      4      good

6       2     good
6       3     good
```

Now, the above data is in sorted manner (total 7 rows). I need to make a group of 2 , 3 or 4 rows separately and generate a graph. In the above data, I made a group of 2 rows. The third row is left alone as there is no other column in 3rd row to form a group. A group can be formed only within the same row. NOT with other rows.

Now, I will check if both the rows have “good” in the info column or not. If both rows have “good” – the group formed is also good , otherwise bad. In the above example, 3rd /last group is “good” group. Rest are all bad group. Once I’m done with all the rows, I will calculate the total no. of Good groups formed/Total no. of groups.

In the above example, the output will be: Total no. of good groups/Total no. of groups  => 1/3.

This is the case of n=2(size of group)

Now, for n=3, we make group of 3 rows and for n=4, we make a group of 4 rows and find the good /bad groups in a similar way. If all the rows in a group has “good” block—the result is good block, otherwise bad.

Example: n= 3

```
2      1       good
2      4       bad
2     6        good

3      2      good

4     1       good
4      4      good
4    6        good

6       2     good
6       3     good
```

In the above case, I left the 4th row and last 2 rows as I can’t make group of 3 rows with them. The first group result is “bad” and last group result is “good”.
Output: 1/ 2

For n= 4:

```
2      1       good
2      4       good
2      6        good
2      7       good

3      2      good

4     1       good
4      4      good
4    6        good

6       2     good
6       3     good
6       4     good
6       5     good
```

In this case, I make a group of 4 and finds the result. The 5th,6th,7th,8th row are left behind or ignored. I made 2 groups of 4 rows and both are “good” blocks. 
Output: 2/2

So, After getting 3 output values for n=2 , n-3, and n=4 I will plot a graph of these values.

Answer (score 1):

Below is code that I think is getting what you are looking for.  It assumes that the data that you described is stored separately in the three datasets named data_2, data_3, and data_4.  Each of these datasets is processed by the %FIND_GOOD_GROUPS macro that determines which groups of X have all "GOOD" values in INFO, then this summary information is appended as a new row to the BASE dataset.  I didn't add the code, but you could calculate the ratio of GOOD_COUNT to *FREQ* in a separate data step, then use a procedure to plot the N value and the ratio.  Hope this gets close to what you're trying to accomplish.

---

```
%******************************************************************************;
%macro main;

   %find_good_groups(dsn=data_2, n=2);
   %find_good_groups(dsn=data_3, n=3);
   %find_good_groups(dsn=data_4, n=4);

   proc print data=base uniform noobs;

%mend main;
%******************************************************************************;
%******************************************************************************;
%macro find_good_groups(dsn=,n=);

   %***************************************************************************;
   %* Sort data by X and Y so that you can use FIRST.X variable in Data step. *;
   %***************************************************************************;
   proc sort data=&dsn;
      by x y;
   run;

   %***************************************************************************;
   %* TEMP dataset uses the FIRST.X variable to reset COUNT and GOOD_COUNT to *;
   %* initial values for each row where X changes. Each row in the X groups   *;
   %* adds 1 to COUNT and sets GOOD_COUNT to 0 (zero) if INFO is ever "BAD".  *;
   %* A record is output if COUNT is equal to the macro parameter &N.         *;
   %***************************************************************************;
   data temp;
      keep good_count n;
      retain count 0 good_count 1 n &n;
      set &dsn;
      by x y;
      if first.x then do;
         count = 0;
         good_count = 1;
      end;
      count = count + 1;
      if good_count eq 1 then do;
         if trim(left(upcase(info))) eq "BAD" then do;
            good_count = 0;
         end;
      end;
      if count eq &n then output;
   run;

   %***************************************************************************;
   %* Summarize the TEMP data to find the number of times that all of the     *;
   %* rows had "GOOD" in the INFO column for each value of X.                 *;
   %***************************************************************************;
   proc summary data=temp;
      id n;
      var good_count;
      output out=n_&n (drop=_type_) sum=;
   run;

   %***************************************************************************;
   %* Append to BASE dataset to retain the sums and frequencies from all of   *;
   %* the datasets. BASE can be used to plot the N / number of Good records.  *;
   %***************************************************************************;
   proc append data=n_&n base=base force; run;

%mend find_good_groups;
%******************************************************************************;
%main
```